# Angular 2 Meteor include bootstrap 3 js file from node_modules

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular

Please could anyone tell me how to include bootstrap JS file in Angular2 Meteor project. This seems the guide but it's empty now [Angular 2 Meteor 3rd-party libraries](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3rd-party-libraries)

It sounds simple but I dont know how, please help!! @@

Answer (score 0):

Well for now I have to copy the bootstrap.js file into the client folder and it is loaded, It works but still waiting for the best practice for this!